# Meaning of a fingering marking

Tags: piano, fingering

Henle's edition of Isaac Albéniz's *Tango* has these two bars:

[image]

What does the line connecting the two 2s across the bar line mean?

Comment: It means that you should slide the same finger to the right, rather than growing a second index finger :-)  But seriously, this notation seems redundant, and perhaps only there as a sort of "[sic]" saying "yes, the second 2 is  not a misprint".

Comment: Also of interest is 'which finger does the1st F# get played with?'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it simply emphasises the suggested fingering, in which finger 2 is used for successive notes, so you have to slide your finger down onto the white key. The motivation for this fingering, rather than the obvious 2-3-4-5 is probably to avoid the akwardness when combined with the thumb on D.